# Output 40 random sums without repeats

Tags: php

I'm creating an online test for my kids based on their school's tests.

I want to output 40 random multiplication sums based on the 1 - 10 times table (except for the 7 & 9 times table). But I don't want to output any that have been outputted before

For example:

**7 X 4 =**

**2 X 5 =**

**12 X 10 =**

**4 X 5 =**

... up to 40 questions...

What is the most elegant way of doing this? I am a bit stumped!

I can get random numbers between 1 - 10 with

```
$numbers = range(1, 10);
shuffle($numbers);
```

But this will still include 7 and 9. Then how do I generate the 40 sums while making sure there are no duplicates?

Thanks!

Comment: To prevent duplicates you need a memory in some form. Either directly by comparing each new proposed pair with the list of those already used, or by first setting up a catalog of existing pairs. Then you shuffle that, always pick the first.

Comment: And a hint: instead of using random seeds you should think about introducing a persistent storage, something like a primitive database, either mysql or maybe even only sqlite. That allows to easily keep track of the learning progress and more often ask those pairs that apparently are difficult to learn.

Comment: Thanks, you've got my brain into gear. I'm not wanting to go down the database route at this stage - that's a bit overkill for now. But I like your idea of setting the catalogue of existing pairs and then shuffle - maybe not overly elegant, but it works. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, have fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$question = array();
$numbers = range(1,10);
$numbers = array_diff($numbers, [7, 9]); // Removing 7 & 9 from array as per requirement
$frontNumbers = range(1,20);
$frontNumbers =  array_merge($frontNumbers, range(1,20));
$frontNumbers =  array_merge($frontNumbers, range(1,10)); // Just to make sure we get required no of questions
shuffle($frontNumbers);
foreach($frontNumbers as $value){
    shuffle($numbers);
   $question[] = $value.','.$numbers[0];
}
$question = array_unique($question);
$question = array_slice($question,0,40);
$count = 0;
foreach($question as $row){
   $count++; 
   echo $count.') '.str_replace(',', ' x ', $row).' = <br>';
}
```